# modifying and protecting cookies

Tags: cookies, forum

I am trying to modify a cookie, specifically the pass_hash cookie that the ipb forums set. I have tried several different extensions for firefox to modify this cookie and set it, adn cannot seem to do so.

The cookie seems to expire as soon as it is created. I am trying to set it to expire one year from now. I can not modify this cookie in any form. Even deleting that cookie, and making a new cookie will not work...possibly since it is being over written.

Why is this the case, and is there any way to force it to stay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, it depends on the server-side. If you on the client side manipulate the cookie to live 'forever', the server still can delete it. If this ipb forum software has a policy of 'one-way' cookies, that is, deletes every cookie and writes a new one, or resets the expire date on the server side, there is nothing you can do about it.

Cheers,

Comment: Cookies are client side...surely I can write protect it or force the server to acknowledge my cookie?

Comment: Cookies are **stored** client-side, but both server and client can read and change them. That's quite a huge difference.

Comment: and you can't stop that or prevent it at all?

Comment: That depends on how you define stop and prevent. If you're happy with setting a cookie over and over again at the client side, when a server deletes it, you have stopped/prevented it. However, I doubt that this will have any practical usage, since the server will most probably not react to the content of the cookie then.

Comment: By the way, give this part of the Wikipedia Cookie article a minute: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Setting_a_cookie
It explains, how cookies get set on client and server side respectively.